# What can cause the list of remote branches to differ between two instances of the same repo?

Tags: git

I find this confusing, but when I run `git branch -r` to see a list of all remote branches I see an extra branch listed in one instances. However, when I run `git ls-remote origin` I see that "extra" branch on both instances. What could have caused this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: If my answered helped you please consider accepting my answer. If not, please help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TLDR/Fix

Execute `git fetch origin` to [fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_description) all branches and/or tags (collectively, "refs" or "references")

*[`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_description) will work too, because this command includes a fetch*

### The reason

`git branch -r` will [list so-called **remote-tracking branches**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#_description). Those are branches that are being tracked from a given remote (like `origin`)

`git ls-remote <repository>` (where `<repository>` will usually be a remote) will [list **references in a remote repository**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote#_description)

### What's happening

`git branch -r` will check all **remote-tracking branches** present in the **local** repository

`git ls-remote <repository>` will list all **available references** (branches are references) present on the server at the time of executing the command